# Match columns with several conditions efficiently

Tags: r

I have a big dataframe in which I have two columns containing dates. For each individual (`id`), `date.x` contains a unique date but `date.y` contains several dates.  I would like to match the dates according to several conditions, so that I have one row per individual with one `date.x` and one `date.y`. By order of preference:

- if there is `date.y` so that `date.x = date.y`, then I want to keep only this `date.y`.
- if there is `date.y` so that `date.x > date.y`, then I want to keep only the closest value of `date.y` that is smaller than `date.x`.
- if there isn't `date.y` so that `date.x > date.y` (i.e if all `date.y` are greater than `date.x`), then I want to keep only the closest value of `date.y` that is greater than `date.x`.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(tibble)

test <- tibble(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6),
  id = rep(rep(1:2, each = 3), 2),
  date.x = rep(c(2002, 2008), each = 6),
  date.y = c(1998, 2000, 2004, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2006, 2008, 2010, 2009, 2010, 2011)
)

# Current form:
# A tibble: 12 x 4
   group    id date.x date.y
   <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 A         1   2002   1998
 2 A         1   2002   2000
 3 A         1   2002   2004
 4 A         2   2002   1997
 5 A         2   2002   1998
 6 A         2   2002   1999
 7 B         1   2008   2006
 8 B         1   2008   2008
 9 B         1   2008   2010
10 B         2   2008   2009
11 B         2   2008   2010
12 B         2   2008   2011
```

```
# expected output:

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  group    id date.x date.y
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1   2002   2000
2 A         2   2002   1999
3 B         1   2008   2008
4 B         2   2008   2009
```

Also, since my dataframe is quite big and makes my RStudio session crash sometimes, I need a solution which is the most economical in memory.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibility.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  group_by(id, date.x) %>% 
  filter(
    date.x == date.y |
    date.x - date.y == min(abs(date.x - date.y)) & date.x > date.y |
    date.x + date.y == min(date.x + date.y) & date.x < date.y
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   id, date.x [4]
  group    id date.x date.y
  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1   2002   2000
2 A         2   2002   1999
3 B         1   2008   2008
4 B         2   2008   2009
```

Comment: Your code works but it relies on the fact that all pairs id - date.x are unique, which is the fact in my example but not in my true dataset. I should have thought about this in my post but can you adapt your solution if date.x = 2002 for individual B - 2 for example?

Comment: Could you please update your example and expected output? I'm not sure I understand how you expect it to change the result. My code checks all the conditions you listed based on the `date.x` and `id` columns. If you want to filter rows independently to the `id` column, just remove `id` in the `group_by` function. If you also want to filter rows based on the `group` column, add it in `group_by`.

Comment: No need to edit my post, you explained the different cases here

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using `case_when`:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  group_by(group,id,date.x) %>%
  summarise(date.y = case_when(unique(date.x) %in% date.y ~ unique(date.x), 
                               any(date.y < unique(date.x)) ~ max(date.y[date.y < unique(date.x)]),
                               all(date.y > unique(date.x)) ~ min(date.y)))
## A tibble: 4 x 4
## Groups:   group, id [4]
#  group    id date.x date.y
#  <chr> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 A         1   2002   2000
#2 A         2   2002   1999
#3 B         1   2008   2008
#4 B         2   2008   2009
```

Comment: Thanks, but that means that if there are other variables in `test`, they are removed from the new tibble. Do you know how to keep them?

Comment: You could add `%>% left_join(test)` to the end.